# Send email from client domain

Tags: email, saas

I am working on developing s simple SaaS offering where clients will be able to self sign-up for the service via the sight, create users in their organization, and set-up various workflows for those users. Part of the process is to have our system send emails to these users to remind them to continue their work or to congratulate them for finishing a step. However, the wrinkle here is that our clients want these emails to appear as if they are coming from them.

So, for example, if we have a client, xyz corp., and they set-up a rule to greet a new user in their first sign-up, they want to have our system trigger an email to that user that appears to come from them.

As part of the sign-up the client is required to provide various information such as an account they would like these emails to come from. (e.g. admin@xyzcorp.com). However, as we are targeting an audience that would tend to have limited IT resources, we are hoping to require very limited participation on their end. So, a full integration with say, the client's exchange server, is less than ideal.

I know that I could spoof the email but that would  likely set-off spam filters.

Comment: If you don’t want to “spoof” it, then you _will_ need the client’s participation – on the lowest possible level imaginable by them letting you use their mail server to send out those mails to begin with, or on a more sophisticated level by having them set up SPF records that mark your mail server as one that is allowed to send out emails in their/their “domain’s” name.

Comment: You didn't actually ask a question. It sounds like you're asking how you can do all of this, which is too broad and not really a programming question. If you're asking for a tool or service recommendation, that's off-topic. Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think keeping the effort on the client side as minimal as possible is always a nice approach but realizing your project without participation on their end won't work without the mails sent from your server being filtered out by the recipients server: Otherwise anybody on this planet could sent mails from anybody's domain.

But when we talk about limited IT resources most of your customers will probably somehow have access to a working mail server to communicate with their customers. Assuming that and as far as I understand the scenario there are two options:

1) Get access to their smtp server (when they have a domain they most likely will have an smtp server)

2) As CBroe mentioned in his comment: Let your customer set up an SPF record and/or DKIM signature record which authorizes your IP to sent mails from your customer's domain

And to be honest: I would consider both options as minimal participation on the customer's side:
(1): Create a new stmp user, copy the credentials and send it to you (or store it in your backend).
(2): Copy and paste a string and sent it to the domain registrar (or set up a DNS record on their own DNS server).